# bmp image not displaying correctly in kivy widget

Tags: kivy, bmp

I have a bmp image that is displayed incorrectly though the original image on disk is OK. See 2nd image below:

[image]

The image is made available through the following code:

```
BoxLayout:
    height: '300dp'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1,1
        Image:
            source: root.actimage
```

In the kivy log file I do not find any error or warning regarding this incorrect displaying of a bmp file.

How could I resolve this?

Comment: Do png's work for you?

Comment: Well, the image itself is a bmp used from within a related application. In order to display it correctly in my kivy app I would like to display it without conversion. However, I have added a conversion function to png so it is displayed now correctly. But strange that kivy has difficulties with displaying bmp images.

Comment: And do other bmp's do the same?

Comment: bmp's shows perfectly here. Can you upload that exact bmp somewhere?

Comment: Yes, all bmp's.

Comment: Okey. Then there is something with your build I guess

Comment: I am running 1.9.1.dev1

Comment: I am also running 1.9.1. py2 or 3? linux or win?

Comment: py2 on windows.

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be a bug: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/4395

Kivy assumes that all BMPs are 32bit.